How is Jesus not of the tribe of Aaron?
JTB's mother, Elizabeth, is from the tribe of Aaron, which is how John obtained the priesthood and the authority to baptize. If Elizabeth is Mary's cousin, how are Mary and Jesus not also from the tribe of Aaron?

Families did not need to marry withing their own tribe.  In any case, if Joseph was of the tribe of Judah and Mary was of the tribe of Levi, then Jesus would be from both tribes.  However, we do not have enough information to settle this question, so we do not know.

Please include scripture as to what scripture clarifies Jesus is not from the specified tribe in your question. More context, including even the nestled scriptures in context on either side of your main scripture in question to plainly show why you have such a question, would likely help others to see what your thoughts and research have been to lead us to your question. This process, though it might take a little extra time, also might help you and/or others to answer your question.

First cousins together have six grandparents, with one set of grandparents in common.
That means that they each have one set of grandparents that aren't in common.
So, if Elizabeth's Aaron ancestry is though her non-common grandparents, there is no reason for Mary to have Aaron ancestors.
G1+G2 ⇒ P1
G3+G4 ⇒ P2 and P3
G5+G6 ⇒ P4

P1+P2 ⇒ Elizabeth
P3+P4 ⇒ Mary

G1, G2, P1, and Elizabeth could have Aaron ancestors, while Mary (and Jesus) might not.
